# SimpleTest for Wordpress plugins

Tags: php, unit-testing, wordpress

Does anyone has any insight on unit-testing wordpress plugins with Simpletest, or other testing packages?

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Wordpress or its plugin architecture.  However I would like to say SimpleTest is seriously outdated.  PHPUnit has way more features and is actively maintained.  A quick search yielded this: http://github.com/johnbintz/mockpress